# how to create a square on top of a given Vector. This square should be orthogonal to the given vector

Tags: python, math, vector, blender

Programming in Python (Blender):
I want to create a square and print all vertices (A;B;C;D) into my console on top of a given Vector. The square should be orthogonal to this vector, like this:[image]

```
def create_verts_around_point(radius, vert):
    # given Vector
    vec = np.array([vert[0], vert[1], vert[2]])

    # side_length of square
    side_length = radius

    # Vctor x-direction (1,0,0)
    x_vec = np.array([1,0,0])

    # Vekctor  y-direction (0,1,0)
    y_vec = np.array([0,1,0])

    # Vector z-direction (0,0,1)
    z_vec = np.array([0,0,1])

    p1 = vec + (side_length/2) * x_vec + (side_length/2) * y_vec + (side_length/2) * z_vec
    p2 = vec - (side_length/2) * x_vec + (side_length/2) * y_vec + (side_length/2) * z_vec
    p3 = vec - (side_length/2) * x_vec - (side_length/2) * y_vec + (side_length/2) * z_vec
    p4 = vec + (side_length/2) * x_vec - (side_length/2) * y_vec + (side_length/2) * z_vec
```

But my output looks like this in the end (Square is always parallel to my x-axis and y-axis):
[image]

Comment: You're going to need trigonometry here.  You need to compute the angle of the vector, and then two of your sides will be at that angle, and two at 90 degrees from that angle.  You're drawing a 2D square at a 3D point.  What plane do you want the square to be in?

Comment: It depends on the given vector right ?
i want to create an cube around this vector, thats why i need 4 points (the other 4 points for this cube are already given) which is orthogonal to this given vector. The given vector is variable. Sry my english is not the best ^^

Comment: You said a square.  Do you actually want a cube?  A cube requires 8 points, not 4 points.  That's OK, if that's what you want, but even then, the cube could be oriented in any direction.  Think of a stick with a cube on the end.  You can spin that cube all the way around, and it's still orthogonal.

Comment: i want a square on top of my vector. Sry forget about the cube i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're really thinking about this problem in 3D, but see if this is close.

I create a square, perpendicular to the X axis.  I then rotate that square based on the angles in x, y, and z.  I then position the square at the end of the vector and plot it.  I add plot points for the origin and the end of the vector, and I duplicate the last point in the square do it draws all the lines.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_verts_around_point(sides, vert):

    x0, y0, z0 = vert

    # Here is the unrotated square.

    half = sides/2
    square = [ 
        [0, -half,-half],
        [0, -half, half],
        [0,  half, half],
        [0,  half,-half],
    ]

    # Now find the rotation in each direction.

    thetax = math.atan2( z0, y0 )
    thetay = math.atan2( z0, x0 )
    thetaz = math.atan2( y0, x0 )

    # Now rotate the cube, first in x.

    cubes = []
    txcos = math.cos(thetax)
    txsin = math.sin(thetax)
    tycos = math.cos(thetay)
    tysin = math.sin(thetay)
    tzcos = math.cos(thetaz)
    tzsin = math.sin(thetaz)
    for x,y,z in square:
        x,y,z = (x, y * txcos - z * txsin, y * txsin + z * txcos)
        x,y,z = (x * txcos - z * txsin, y, x * txsin + z * txcos)
        x,y,z = (x * txcos - y * txsin, x * txsin + y * txcos, z)
        cubes.append( (x0+x, y0+y, z0+z) )

    return cubes

point = (10,10,10)
square = create_verts_around_point(5, point)
points = [(0,0,0),point] + square + [square[0]]
x =  [p[0] for p in points]
y =  [p[1] for p in points]
z =  [p[2] for p in points]

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot( x, y, z )
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Plot output]

Comment: Thank you for explaning it! I will try to use this in my programm tomorrow and give you an update how it went.

Comment: I tested it with my code and it worked. Thank you!